# images won't load on iphone

Tags: iphone, image

Hi I am trying to built a page with html/css and javascript.
Everything seem to work when I test in on windows browser but it won't load the images on iphone.
I tried several iphones with no luck. I tried Safari and Chrome. I followed all the instructions for settings but nothing. It doesn't even recognise that there is an image in the code.

I found out that in css : *, *:after, *:before{ content:""; } created the issue. Any way around it ? I messes up with all my layout if I delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

Found out, instead of writing:

```
 *, *:after, *:before{
content:"";
clear:both;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-family: 'Sulphur Point', sans-serif;
```

}

I separated

```
*:after, *:before{
content:"";
```

}
and added

```
*,*:after, *:before{
clear:both;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-family: 'Sulphur Point', sans-serif;
```

}

Images now appear in iphones as well.